# Groovy: is there a way to return all occurrences of a String as a List of Integer offsets?

Tags: java, string, groovy

Given a String, I know Groovy provides convenience methods like
 [`String.findAll(String, Closure)`](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/lang/String.html#findAll%28java.lang.String%2C%20groovy.lang.Closure%29)

> Finds all occurrences of a regular
>   expression string within a String. Any
>   matches are passed to the specified
>   closure. The closure is expected to
>   have the full match in the first
>   parameter. If there are any capture
>   groups, they will be placed in
>   subsequent parameters.

However, I am looking for a similar method where the closure receives either the Matcher object or the int offset of the match. Is there such a beast?

Or, if not: is there a common way to return the offsets of all matches for a given String or Pattern as a Collection or Array of Integers / ints? (Commons / Lang or Guava are both OK, but I'd prefer plain Groovy).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know of anything that currently exists, but you could add the method to the metaClass of String if you wanted...  Something like:

```
String.metaClass.allIndexOf { pat ->
  def (ret, idx) = [ [], -2 ]
  while( ( idx = delegate.indexOf( pat, idx + 1 ) ) >= 0 ) {
    ret << idx
  }
  ret
}
```

Which can be called by:

```
"Finds all occurrences of a regular expression string".allIndexOf 's'
```

and returns (in this case)

```
[4, 20, 40, 41, 46]
```

**Edit**

Actually...a version which can work with regular expression parameters would be:

```
String.metaClass.allIndexOf { pat ->
  def ret = []
  delegate.findAll pat, { s ->
    def idx = -2
    while( ( idx = delegate.indexOf( s, idx + 1 ) ) >= 0 ) {
      ret << idx
    }
  }
  ret
}
```

Which can then be called like:

```
"Finds all occurrences of a regular expression string".allIndexOf( /a[lr]/ )
```

to give:

```
[6, 32]
```

**Edit 2**

And finally this code as a Category

```
class MyStringUtils {
  static List allIndexOf( String str, pattern ) {
    def ret = []
    str.findAll pattern, { s ->
      def idx = -2
      while( ( idx = str.indexOf( s, idx + 1 ) ) >= 0 ) {
        ret << idx
      }
    }
    ret
  }
}

use( MyStringUtils ) {
  "Finds all occurrences of a regular expression string".allIndexOf( /a[lr]/ )
}
```

Comment: Thanks (+1). Let's say I have a test class that needs this functionality in each method. Where would I put it? In a static initializer?

Comment: Once called, this will be available for every instance of `String` created after that point, so yeah somewhere that is only called once early on would be a good place.  To avoid polluting the metaClass of String, you could also do it as a Category, but you'd then need to do:  `use( MyCategory ) { "a string".allIndexOf 's' }`

Comment: wow, I'd never heard of Categories before, [that's even cooler](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/GROOVY/Groovy+Categories)!

Comment: @sean they are a really nice way to add functionality without polluting the metaClass too heinously.  I've added the code as a Category to the answer :-)

Answer (score 3):

I guess something like

```
def str = " a long string with some regexpable text in"
def lastIndex = 0
def indexes = str.findAll(~/e/) { match ->
    lastIndex = str.indexOf(match, lastIndex+1)
    return lastIndex
}
```

would perfectly do the job, as this example returns

```
[23, 26, 28, 34, 37]
```

in Groovy Console

Comment: Nice working solution, thanks (+1), but I'm looking for something even more concise.